# Ler array vindo de um campo

Tags: php, sql

em uma consulta sql, ela me retorna esse valor  10,30,40,50 do campos" mark_ups_range"

Como ler e quabrar em linhas esse valores?
exemolo

10

30

40

50

```
$sql1 = "SELECT mark_ups_range FROM config_politicas WHERE id_transfer = '1' ";
$resultado1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die( mysql_error());
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado1)) {

$id2=$linha['mark_ups_range'];// 10,30,40,50

}
$arr = explode(', ', $id2);
foreach ($arr as $v) {
echo '<br>';
echo $arr;
}
```

Comment: Tem um espaço a mais no seu explode

Comment: Substitua isso `$arr = explode(', ', $id2);` por isso `$arr = explode(',', $id2);`.

Comment: me retorna assim  Array
Array
Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu `explode` tem um espaço a mais. Outro problema é que a cada repetição do `foreach` você esta imprimindo o valor de `$arr` quando na verdade deveria imprimir o valor de `$v`. Faça da seguinte forma:

```
$arr = explode(',', $id2);
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    echo '<br>';
    echo $v;
}
```

O `as` do `foreach` vai fazer com que a cada repetição seja pego um item do `array` e armazenado na variável a direita, que no caso é `$v`.